# What services are needed for Google Play Store to work?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I've got a Chinese Lenovo Z5 phone and an Amazon Fire HD 8, which do not come with `Google Play Store` by default. I know how to manually sideload APK and install Play Store, however I am not sure about the dependencies.

As far as I know the `Google Play Services` is an absolute requirements. Other than that, some services for account and/or authentication are needed to ensure normal operation. What are they? I've done this a long time ago so I cannot remember.

Comment: Don't think anything except for Play Services is needed. Not sure if sideloading it would make it work, though.

Comment: You can take a look at [microG](https://microg.org/). It provides a light-weight alternative to Google Services which is much more privacy friendly. And there's reports of working Play Store installations with it – though, unless you've bought apps that use Play's license check, you could simply use Yalp or Aurora instead of Play Store and keep it light-weighter, not even needing Play Services at all. See [my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/apps_markets) for the links to Yalp & Co. And especially F-Droid ;)